# How to force specific version of a transitive dependency (netty-codec-http) in gradle?

Tags: gradle, amazon-s3, dependencies, netty, owasp

I am trying to use version `4.1.100.Final` for the `netty-codec-http` library as the OWASP dependency checker marks the `netty*` dependancies as `HIGH`. It is pulled out by amazon `s3` dependency. Here is my `build.gradle` file. I am using gradle `8.3` and `jdk11`.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.16'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id "org.owasp.dependencycheck" version "8.2.1"
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.100.Final'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.21.0")
    implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core"
    implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:s3"
    implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:route53"
    implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:route53resolver"
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html) link to setup AWS on gradle.

The dependency checker still shows the `4.1.97.Final` version and marks it as `HIGH`. I am using the following command to generate the OWASP report:

```
./gradlew dependencyCheckAnalyze
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start you should stop using the Spring dependency management plugin. It is an obsolete relict from times when Gradle did not have built-in BOM support and [even its maintainer recommends not to use it anymore](https://www.linen.dev/s/gradle-community/t/2579116/what-is-the-proper-way-to-apply-a-bom-in-a-library-project-i#a7d4a60a-ab60-48dc-8477-f3f4462d1e6a). By now it does more harm than good and does not really have any added value. You should instead just use [the built-in BOM support using `platform(...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import).

This will most probably also resolve your issue already, as that plugin also does a similar forcing like you try to do and obviously overwrites your try to force the version.

But actually, you should also not do this big-hammer forcing of a version, but instead set a strict version constraint like with

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation("io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.100.Final!!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this also apply to the testImplementation block?

Comment: Sure, `testImplementation` is just a configuration like `implementation` too.